Locally trivial bundle with fibre an H-space
I apologize if this question is naive or if it is a well-known classical result, in which case I apologize in advance:
By a locally trivial fibre bundle over $B$ with fibre $F$ I mean a continuous map $p:E\to B$ such that for any point of the base $b\in B$ there exists an open neighborhood $b\in U$ with a homeomorphism $\varphi :p^{-1}(U)\to U\times F$ (local trivialisation) such that $pr_1(\varphi (x))=p(x),$ for all $x\in U$ (here $pr_1$ denotes the projection onto the first factor).
Suppose we have a locally trivial fibre bundle $p: E\to B$ with fibre $F$, where $F$ is an H-space equipped with a multiplication $m: F \times F \to F$. Is it possible to choose a suitable atlas $\{U_\alpha\}$ of $B$ with local trivialisations $ \varphi_\alpha $ such that the corresponding transition functions $g_{\alpha\beta}:U_{\alpha }\cap U_{\beta }\to Homeo(F)$ preserve the H-space multiplication on $F$? (Specifically, for all $x \in U_\alpha \cap U_\beta $ and $f_1,f_2\in F,$ the following condition must hold:
$$
g_{\alpha\beta}(x)(m(f_1, f_2)) = m(g_{\alpha\beta}(x)(f_1), g_{\alpha\beta}(x)(f_2)).
$$ ).
Thanks in advance.

This question deserves a more elaborate answer than I would have time to write right now, but this question is already interesting and with a negative answer if you take $F$ to be a topological group. The keywords to look up are "principal bundle" and "reduction of structure group".

Thank you for your input and the suggested keywords! I will definitely look into "principal bundle" and "reduction of structure group." If you have any references or could briefly outline why the answer is negative in the case of F being a topological group, I would greatly appreciate it.

Here's a "stupid" counter-example. Take $F=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. A locally trivial fiber bundle with fiber $F$ is the same thing as a $2$-fold covering space. Non-trivial examples of these abound, e.g. $S^1\rightarrow S^1,\,z\mapsto z^2$. The only homeomorphism of $F$ preserving the multiplication is the identity, though, so  an atlas satisfying your condition yields a global trivialization of the bundle, so any non-trivial $2$-fold covering is a counter-example.
In general, you are looking at a fiber bundle with fiber $F$ whose structure group is the maximally possible group $\mathrm{Homeo}(F)$ (be wary that this is not necessarily a topological group) and the existence of an atlas you want is a reduction of the structure group to $\mathrm{Aut}(F)$, the group of automorphisms of $F$. The question of whether this is possible for a specific bundle is, in general, very difficult. It does usually not hold for all fiber bundles with fiber $F$ (under mild assumptions, that is equivalent to $\mathrm{Aut}(F)\hookrightarrow\mathrm{Homeo}(F)$ being a weak homotopy equivalence). To get acquainted with the concepts, I recommend Stephen Mitchell's notes.

Thank you for the detailed explanation!  I now see how the condition on the atlas implies a global trivialization, effectively ruling out non-trivial bundles under the given constraints.
The connection to whether  $\mathrm{Aut}(F) \hookrightarrow \mathrm{Homeo}(F)$ is a weak homotopy equivalence is very insightful and suggests a much deeper relationship between the topology of $F$ and the classification of fiber bundles.
Thank you also for pointing me toward Stephen Mitchell's notes. I will look into them to get a better grasp of these concepts.
